# 2d list functions, i cant figure out how to print input, python

Tags: python, list

my code is trying to set the point in the list they chose to an x, please assist in changing the code so that it works, here's the code:

```
position = input("x or y: ")
board = [
    [" ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " "],
    [" ", " ", " "],
    [" "]
    ]
gamewon = False
game_start = "Enter \"s\" when ready to start game";







def game1(placement1, placement2):
    placement1 = input("row: ")
    placement2 = input("column: ")
    board[placement1][placement2] = "x"
    print(board)
```

Comment: So, it is a maze game?

Comment: Did you tried [pprint](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/pprint.html) ?

Comment: Your `game1()` got some logic and syntax problems - is that you're stuck?

Comment: The `input` function returns a string.  You need integers.  `placement1 = int(input("row: "))` and `placement2 = input("column: ")`

Answer (score 0):

```
 #Assign values to the parameters.
 placement1 = None
 placement2 = None
 board = [
[" ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " "],
[" ", " ", " "],
[" "]
]

 def game1(placement1, placement2, board): #Add board as a parameter
        placement1 = int(input("row: "))
        placement2 = int(input("column: ")) 
        board[placement1][placement2] = "x" #Input has to be an integer for this to work
        print(board)

#Call the function
game1(placement1, placement2, board)
```

This will change the index in the nested list to an x after user Input